# Uploading a complete folder in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, file-upload, folder

In Sharepoint 2010, I was able to upload entire folders, by choosing Upload Multiple Files and dragging and dropping the folder into the designated location. Or by selecting the folder at upload point.

However, in 2013, I am not able to find out how to do this in Sharepoint 2013.

Dragging and dropping a folder into a library gives the message:

> **Folders** and invalid files can't be dragged to upload.

And I can't seem a select a folder in the browse window that opens up from the "Choose a file" textbox of "Add a document" window, either.

So how can I upload an entire folder into Sharepoint 2013 at one-go?

Answer (score 4):

What about "open with Explorer" and then drag and drop your structure?

[image]

Comment: Hi Daniel! Can you please add more details about how to use "Open in explorer" to make your answer a bit more useful :)

Comment: @Daniel Unfortunately, this was one of the first things I tried, but it just seems to freeze then crash my browser (IE). I will try to troubleshoot that, if this is in fact the only way to do this in SP. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To expand a bit on Daniels answer, if you select "Open with Explorer" on the library ribbon. It will open up the document library in a windows explorer view. From here you would locate the files in a second windows explorer view. Then drag and drop into the SharePoint document library windows explorer pop-up.

Sharepoint Document Library      ----------------------------Folders that need to be uploaded

[image]